# SQL Server : I'm trying to create a trigger that when inserted data in table Reservations it updates only specific row but not all of them

Tags: sql-server

I'm kinda new to SQL Server and I have this task from school I'm trying to solve. I have 3 tables `Flight`, `number_seats` and `reservations`.

I'm trying to create a trigger so when data is inserted into table `Reservations`, it subtract 1 seat from the table `Number_Seats` in column `Total_Number_Seats`.

The problem I'm having is that my `WHERE` targets all of the rows so when I insert data into table `Reservations`, it affects all rows and not just the particular row with same `FLIGHT_ID`.

I realise my `WHERE` clause is not specific enough but I can't figure out how to write it so it targets specific row that got inserted. So please help if you can :).

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ajSad]
ON [dbo].[Reservations]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Number_Seats
    SET Total_Number_Seats = Total_Number_Seats - 1
    FROM Number_Seats 
    JOIN Flights ON Number_Seats.FLIGHT_ID = FLIGHTS.FLIGHT_ID
    JOIN Reservations ON Flights.Flight_ID = Reservations.Flight_ID
    WHERE Reservations.FLIGHT_ID = Number_Seats.Flight_ID
END
```

```
INSERT INTO reservations (ID_Rezervacije, ID_Klijenta, FLIGHT_ID)
VALUES (5, 5, 5);
```

Comment: In MS SQL Server After insert trigger contains virtual table inserted where there are inserted records.You need to add JOIN to it

Comment: Do NOT assume that a single row is inserted - that is a basic and common flaw for trigger beginners. For triggers there are 2 virtual tables that are populated by the engine containing the rows affected. They are "inserted" and "deleted". For an insert statement (or inserts caused by a merge statement), the new rows can be found in the inserted table. Simply sum the rows by flight from inserted and then use that to update the other table.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is not that you're updating all the rows its that you're subtracting 1 from them. You should be setting the number of seats equal to the seating capacity minus the number of reservations.

Comment: I'm trying to make it work as in a reservation comes in with Flight_ID 5. In table Number_Seats there is Flight_ID which is foreign key and there is  Total_Number_Seats wich already have a number of lets say 150. So when data is inserted in table Reservation it updates table Number_Seats from specific FLIGHT_ID. Probblem is that its update other FLIGHT_IDs and subtracking -1 from them aswell not just one with same flight_ID that its conected to.

Comment: You've already been told that you need to reference the inserted table and not the actual table dbo.Reservations. There are many examples of writing triggers - many of them bad. But they can all be found by simply searching, reading, and examining the logic to learn how to write this code. You need to drop this idea that you can subtract 1 in your logic. You need to count the rows by flight and subtract that number from the available seats for each flight found in the inserted table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger needs to use the `inserted` virtual table to only update the row(s) for the relevant `flight_Id(s)`

The `inserted` table in the context of the trigger will contain all the rows that were inserted in a single batch - this could be one or many and you need to assume it can be more than one.

You need to count the number of new reservations (presumably it's 1 row per reservation) and group by each `flight_Id` and then decrement the total number for each `flight_Id`

```
with t as (
    select flight_Id, Count(*) tot
    from inserted
    group by flight_Id
)

update ns set
    total_number_seats -= tot
from t
join number_seats ns on ns.flight_Id=t.flight_Id
```

Comment: Thank you so much man! It works like a charm! I'm still new in SQL and i need to go step by step to figure out this code its way to advance for my knowledge that i got in a month. Thanks once again!